# Create new lists inside of a list based on object names

Tags: r, list

I have a list of objects, similar pattern to the following list. The list only consists of the names of said objects, for simplicity.

```
List1
    A1_B1.C1
    A1_B2.C2 
    A1_B3.C3
    A2_B1.C1
    A2_B2.C2 
    A2_B3.C3
    A3_B1.C1
    A3_B2.C2 
    A3_B3.C3
```

I would like to concatenate all the similar `B` data into new lists.

```
List2
  B1
    A1_B1.C1   
    A2_B1.C1
    A3_B1.C1
  B2
    A1_B2.C1   
    A2_B2.C2
    A3_B2.C3
  B3
    A1_B3.C1   
    A2_B3.C2
    A3_B3.C3
```

I have played around with some regex codes to try and split the names of the objects by before and after the `.` but am not having much success.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a `vector` or `list.  Are thse object identifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be `split` using the extracted substring of 'B'

```
split(v1, gsub("A\\d+_|\\.C\\d+", "", v1))
#$B1
#[1] "A1_B1.C1" "A2_B1.C1" "A3_B1.C1"

#$B2
#[1] "A1_B2.C2" "A2_B2.C2" "A3_B2.C2"

#$B3
#[1] "A1_B3.C3" "A2_B3.C3" "A3_B3.C3"
```

NOTE: It is not clear whether these are object identifiers or not

The OP uses a different string pattern

```
split(v2, gsub("^[^_]+\\_|\\..*$", "", v2))
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("A1_B1.C1", "A1_B2.C2", "A1_B3.C3", "A2_B1.C1", "A2_B2.C2", 
 "A2_B3.C3", "A3_B1.C1", "A3_B2.C2", "A3_B3.C3")

v2 <- "GenetypeA_Drug1.ValueA"
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting, I am a bit confused on what the code means, and this makes it difficult to implement on my own data. For example, object identifiers could be named GenetypeA_Drug1.ValueA, GenetypeA_Drug2.ValueB and GenetypeB_Drug1.ValueA. This is why splitting between the . might be a good strategy.

Comment: @Krutik  If your string is `str1 <- "GenetypeA_Drug1.ValueA"; gsub("^[^_]+\\_|\\..*$", "", str1)
[1] "Drug1"`

Comment: @Krutik  Wouldn't this help

Comment: Hi Akrun, this did not honestly do the trick because it split my data into an odd assortment. Instead I found using `lapply(split.default(df, sub("(Drug\\d+).*", "\\1", names(genetic_data))), as.list) -> X` worked better.

Comment: @Krutik  But, I was showing it on a vector instead of data.frame.  If it is data.frame, `split.default` should work

Comment: Oh I see, this is my bad, I did not explain the data properly. Yes split.default did work.